# How to access instances in a nested function?

Tags: python, kivy

Im trying to access the value instance in the nested function. don't know how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
    notifications_screen = self.manager.get_screen('notif')
    def listener(event):
        print(event.event_type)  # can be 'put' or 'patch'
        print(event.path)  # relative to the reference, it seems
        print(event.data)  # new data at /reference/event.path. None if deleted
        notifications = event.data
        if notifications.items() == None:
            return
        else:
            for key, value in notifications.items():
                print()
                notifications_screen.notificationslist.adapter.data.extend([value])
```

Comment: The value in the for loop?

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3, you can declare `value` as a `nonlocal` variable inside the inner function.

See [Python nonlocal keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_nonlocal.asp)

```
def myfunc1():
  x = "John"  # assign x to some dummy variable to be overwritten
  def myfunc2():
    nonlocal x
    x = "hello"
  myfunc2()
  return x

print(myfunc1())
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I then access it  from outside the function

Comment: You can access it as if it’s in the outer function.

Comment: @Tim ive tried cant call it outside the nested function

Comment: you need to first declare the variable `value: int` (in python 3.5+) or assign a dummy value: 'value=None', then call the nested function. After that, the value should be accessible.

Comment: @Tim thats what I did and I still cant call it outside the parent function, tried assigning it to a self value and it returns None

Comment: @Matthew1998 to call it outside the parent function, you need global instead of nonlocal